Why pass void pointer instead of custom type?
Setup
I'm taking over code from another person. I found a coding pattern that seems odd to me. This is for an embedded 32 bit PIC processor, in case that's relevant.
They have a custom typedef in a header file similar to the following:
typedef struct {
     custom_object obj;
     char** list_text;
     uint8_t length;
     void (*func)(void* this_obj);
     //other variables here
} custom_list;

But whenever this custom_list type is passed to a function, the function is defined like this:
void custom_function(void* this_obj) {
    custom_list *list = (custom_list*) this_obj;

    //miscellaneous code here... 
}

So, they read in the variable as pointer to void, then recast it as pointer to custom_list inside the function.
Added the following to address comments
Note: also added the func element to the definition above and clarified some wording
There are two ways I've found that this function is called.

When inside of one of these functions and calling another one, it is called by directly passing the void pointer version of the object, this_obj:
custom_function(this_obj);

These functions are normally called via a pointer within the very object that is getting passed (e.g. list.func = &custom_function). The functions are being used as a pseudo-method in a pseudo-class I guess. So, the calls typically go:
list->func((void*)list)


where list is of type custom_list
Note that for case 1, previous operations before the call use the casted custom_list pointer variable list to make changes to its elements (e.g. list->length = X).
Since both variables are "just" pointers, it's the same memory location being changed, but it makes it difficult to follow the code since it APPEARS that one variable is manipulated but another is passed to the next function.
As a side note... in case it's also relevant. To not get into debate about global variables, I left out that char** list is used to point to a GLOBAL list variable pointer. In these functions, that global list is manipulated, rather than performing actions on the pointer within the struct / object itself. I believe they did this in an attempt to save memory. Only one object of custom_list is used at a time. Before another custom_list object is used, the global list is cleared with free, then the next object puts new data in the list using malloc. Personally, I find this makes this code really hard to follow.
Original Question
Why not just pass as type pointer to custom_list, like so?
void custom_function(custom_list* list) {

    //miscellaneous code here... 
}

Isn't passing it as pointer to void then recasting it extra steps? Wouldn't this be a bad practice... were they doing this just to work around a compiler checker error? Or am I missing something, is there some advantage or necessity to the first approach?

Is custom_function being called directly, or is it passed as a callback to something else?

This is usually because there's a generic intermediary function. For instance, take a look at how qsort() calls the comparison function.

In most systems there's no overhead due to casting from one pointer type to another, because all pointers are the same.

@Barmar "because all pointers are the same" --> common enough in a PIC processor to find object pointers and function pointer of a different size.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Since you can't legally cast between object and function pointers, that's not really relevant.

@Barmar: This again? There is no rule in the C standard against converting between object and function pointers. Roughly, we can say the C standard partitions program behaviors into five classes: A—things it defines completely, B—things it defines partially (some of which it requires an implementation to document), C—things it does not define and does not require a diagnostic for, D—things it does not define and requires a diagnostic for, and E—things it prohibits (this is almost empty). Converting between object and function pointers is in C, not E or even D. Everything in A to D is allowed.

You have not shown how the function is called. Your post says “it is called like this:”, but then it shows a definition, not a call. Show a call, with context.

@EricPostpischil good point. I reworded that, and added two ways I've seen it called into my question. I also added some more details I found.

There can be multiple reasons for this. For example the function could be used as an argument for another more general function somewhere.
Here is a simple example, which is not exactly practical C code, but is easy to understand. It is a simple implementation of a map function, applying a given function to every element in an array.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void map(int len, void** array, void (*operator)(void*)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        operator(array[i]);
}

void caesar_encode(void* val) {
    char* str = val;
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (!isalpha(str[i]))
            continue;
        char offset = islower(str[i]) ? 'a' : 'A';
        str[i] = (str[i] - offset + 4) % 26 + offset;
    }
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    map(argc - 1, (void**) argv + 1, caesar_encode);
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

This program applies the Caesar encoding to every alphabetic character in the arguments passed to this program.
A practical example of something like this is pthread_create used to create a new thread object.
pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread, const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr, void *(*start_routine)(void *), void *restrict arg)

The function the thread starts with has to have the signature void *(*start_routine)(void *) allowing you to pass any data you like (packed in a struct for example).

The other reason could be that the person who wrote the code did not like opaque pointer types. A header could look something like this:
...
typedef struct custom_list* CustomList;
CustomList create_custom_list();
void destroy_custom_list(CustomList);
...

So maybe the person who wrote the code simply did not like opaque pointer types and is not used to them or the code came from a time before they were a thing. I am just speculating here at this point.

Thank you for the response. I can understand needing to pass as pointer to void to create a function that could potentially accept multiple different data types (this just gave me an idea for another program I'm working on and was using overloaded functions). In this particular case, though, the type is always known. Though there are a few different similar types in the code I'm looking at, say custom_list, custom_obj, custom_thing... each function uniquely applies only to one type.

The way the struct is defined:
typedef struct {
     custom_object obj;
     char** list_text;
     uint8_t length;
     void (*func)(void* this_obj);
     //other variables here
} custom_list;

The func member can't specify a parameter of type custom_list because the type hasn't yet been defined.
The proper way to do this would be to add a tag to the struct.  Then a pointer to it can be referenced in the struct definition:
typedef struct _custom_list {
     custom_object obj;
     char** list_text;
     uint8_t length;
     void (*func)(struct _custom_list* this_obj);
     //other variables here
} custom_list;

Then the function that would be assigned to this pointer can be defined with the proper type:
void custom_function(custom_list* list) {

    //miscellaneous code here... 
}


In context, this now makes sense. With the update, showing more of the members of the structure:
typedef struct {
     custom_object obj;
     char** list_text;
     uint8_t length;
     void (*func)(void* this_obj);
     //other variables here
} custom_list;

If the function pointed to by func, in this case custom_function, takes a parameter of type custom list you can't reference that type within the definition of the type. That is to say, if it were written:
typedef struct {
     custom_object obj;
     char** list_text;
     uint8_t length;
     void (*func)(custom_list* this_obj);
     //other variables here
} custom_list;

It will fail with error: unknown type name 'custom_list' because it doesn't know what custom_list is yet because it hasn't actually been fully defined.
This is an attempt to basically make a C++ like class, or pseudo-class in C. C++ classes assume an object of the class type is one of the inputs to any member methods without even having to explicitly state it. In C you have to do it as a void pointer to the structure and you just have make sure that you're pointing to the correct type in your code as now it can't be checked.

You would need to use typedef struct custom_list {...} custom_list; and void (*func)(struct custom_list* this_obj) for this to work. You cannot use a type you have yet to define, but you can use an incomplete struct.
